# CTRL+F search for "xx *anything* xx"

Tags: sublimetext2, notepad++, textpad

I am trying to find and replace all for loops in my (js) code with slightly different syntax. I want to find every for loop that used the syntax "for ( *any code here* ){". Is there a way to find all such instances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a regular expression question I think.  In SublimeText2 start the search functionality.  Make sure regular expressions are on (first button, labeled `.*`) and the search for `for\s*\(.*?\)\s*\{`.

Answer (score 2):

Enable the regex option and type `for \(.+\)\{`

Explanation:
the backslashes "escape" the parentheses and brace. In other words, they tell the regex that those are the characters within the search and not part of a regex command. The `.` searches for any character and the `+` modifies that to include one or more instances of any character.

Here's a screen shot of sublime text
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You want to search by regular expression. Notepad++ supports this, not sure about Sublime Text but I would image it does also. With regular expression enabled, search for

```
xx.+xx
```

This will search for the characters xx, followed by any character (**.**) as many times as it can find it (**+**), followed by the characters xx. This should give you the result you are looking for.

[Here is a article](http://markantoniou.blogspot.com/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html) with some information about using regular expressions in Notepad++